# Can't get anything back on some web pages using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this [page](https://resumes.indeed.com/search?l=&q=python&searchFields=jt) of job posts, the posts are buried in a bunch of divs but ultimately contained in an unordered list, when I try to retrieve the list using `find_all` I get `None` returned either by using the tag id or class. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

```py
url = "https://resumes.indeed.com/search?l=&q=python&searchFields=jt"
source = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
match = soup.find_all("ul", class_="rezemp-ResumeSearchPage-resultsList")
print(match)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```py
list = []
for m in match:
  list.append(m)
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from splinter import Browser
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

executable_path = {'executable_path':ChromeDriverManager().install()}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path, headless = False)
```

```
url = "https://resumes.indeed.com/search?l=&q=python&searchFields=jt"
browser.visit(url)
html = browser.html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
match = soup.find_all("ul", class_="rezemp-ResumeSearchPage-resultsList")

# This is the next you get but it's not structured, not sure if that's what you are looking for.

match[0].text
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I noticed that the given URL doesn't have any element using class

```
rezemp-ResumeSearchPage-resultsList
```

So I change this to "https://resumes.indeed.com/search?l=&lmd=all&q=python&searchFields=jt", i.e. choose 'show all resumes' on that website.

then use selenium to load js:

```
import lxml
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

url = "https://resumes.indeed.com/search?l=&lmd=all&q=python&searchFields=jt"

browser=webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,executable_path="***\\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
match = soup.find_all("ul", class_="rezemp-ResumeSearchPage-resultsList")
print(match)
```

Got it
[image]

Comment: Can you explain to me why exactly doesn't it work without selenium?

Comment: It depends on the type of page you scrape: static or dynamic. For a dynamic page, the real content won't generate until javascript code is executed. Selenium can simulate a browser to execute the js, after that, we can get the real content. And you can refer to 'Web Scraping with Python, 2nd Edition' published by O'Reilly. In chapter 11, more details about dynamic HTML are given